# How to sort blocks of text lines in file?

Tags: java, file, sorting

I have a text file consisting of ID, persons name and surname, bank balance and date of account creation. I somehow need to sort this text file by surname and balance, but I don't know how.

```
ID:41
Name and surname: Andris Lietis
Balance: 30000 Eur
Created: 31.03.2019

ID:33
Name and surname: Rainis Maize
Balance: 2000 Eur
Created:  32.03.2019

ID:34
Name and surname: Akmens Liepins
Balance: 123 Eur
Created:  29.03.2019

ID:35
Name and surname: Karlis Maiznieks
Balance: 32000 Eur
Created:  04.04.2019
```

So I was first thinking about somehow reading that file and when I approach one of ID line, I read next three lines and somehow storing those 4 lines in some sort of a block/variable, then doing the same with other blocks. My friend mentioned making objects and comparing, but I don't have any experience with that and as I look up in the google, this really confuses me.

```
    public static void Sakartosana(String nosaukums) throws IOException {


        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nosaukums));
        String s;
//I understand that I need to somehow sort this with selection.sort
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.startsWith("ID:")) {

            }

        }
        br.close();

    }
```

This is how I read the line by line, I have many methods with different tasks reading file like this.

The expected result would be like this :

```
ID:41
Name and surname: Andris Lietis
Balance: 30000 Eur
Created: 31.03.2019

ID:34
Name and surname: Akmens Liepins
Balance: 123 Eur
Created:  29.03.2019

ID:35
Name and surname: Karlis Maiznieks
Balance: 32000 Eur
Created:  04.04.2019

ID:33
Name and surname: Rainis Maize
Balance: 2000 Eur
Created:  32.03.2019
```

Comment: It is time you start organizing the blocks of texts into a class. 

Create a object of that class, then use Comparator to sort.

Comment: Your friend is right: create some class that is able to hold the data for each block. That can be as simple as having a simple string array per block but I'd suggest having something more descriptive, e.g. a class that holds id, name, surname, balance and create date. Then create instances of that class from the data in the file (you create a new instance every time you read a new id), put them into a list, sort them using a comparator (compare their name and surname) and finally write them back to the file.

Comment: Your friend is right. Create a class named `Block` with those fields : `id`, `nameSurname`, `balance`, `created`. Then, parse your text file and create a `List<Block>`. Then, you can sort them with `Collections.sort(blocks, Comparator.comparing(Block::getId));` or `Collections.sort(blocks, Comparator.comparing(Block::getNameSurname));` or any other `Comparator` you want.